# Vectorize Fisher's Exact Test

Tags: optimization, csv, r, statistics, bioinformatics

I have two data frames/ lists of data, `humanSplit` and `ratSplit`, and they are of the form

> ```
> > ratSplit$Kidney_F_GSM1328570
>   ratGene        ratReplicate alignment RNAtype
> 1    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570         7     REV
> 2    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570        12     REV
> 3    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570         4     REV
> ```

and

> ```
> > humanSplit$Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt
>    humanGene                            humanReplicate alignment RNAtype
> 53     ZFP28 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         5     reg
> 55     RC3H1 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         9     reg
> 56     IFI27 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         4     reg
> ```

And another file used below is geneList of the form:

> ```
> ABAT,Abat
> ABCA1,Abca1
> ABCA12,Abca12
> ABCA2,Abca2
> ABCA3,Abca17
> ABCA4,Abca4
> ABCA5,Abca5
> ```

now I want to do Fisher's exact test between all the elements pair combination between `ratSplit` and `humanSplit` after some data manipulation. And ultimately want to write the result of fisher's test in a .csv file. Right now I am doing double `for` loops. But I am wondering how I can use `sapply` or other related things to make it more efficient.

I am currently doing the following thing:

Here I am first making a `data.frame` `result` where I store/append all the information got from fisher's test in a pair in each step. Then finally when the whole loop is done, I write the final `result` in a .csv file. my understanding is to use `sapply` I need to transform the inside of the loop into a function and then call `sapply`. But I am not sure what's the best way to optimize it.

```r
result <- data.frame(humanReplicate = "human_replicate", ratReplicate = "rat_replicate", pvalue = "p-value", alternative = "alternative_hypothesis", 
                     Conf.int1 = "conf.int1", Conf.int2 ="conf.int2", oddratio = "Odd_Ratio")
for(i in 1:length(ratSplit)) {
  for(j in 1:length(humanSplit)) {
    ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[i])
    humanReplicateName <- names(humanSplit[j])

    #merging above two based on the one-to-one gene mapping as in geneList defined above.
    mergedHumanData <-merge(geneList,humanSplit[[j]], by.x = "human", by.y = "humanGene")
    mergedRatData <- merge(geneList, ratSplit[[i]], by.x = "rat", by.y = "ratGene")

    mergedHumanData <- mergedHumanData[,c(1,2,4,5)] #rearrange column
    mergedRatData <- mergedRatData[,c(2,1,4,5)]  #rearrange column
    mergedHumanRatData <- rbind(mergedHumanData,mergedRatData) #now the columns are "human", "rat", "alignment", "RNAtype"

    agg <- aggregate(RNAtype ~ human+rat, data= mergedHumanRatData, FUN=getGeneType) #agg to make HmYn form
    HmRnTable <- table(agg$RNAtype) #table of HmRn ie RNAtype in human and rat.

    #now assign these numbers to variables HmYn. Consider cases when some form of HmRy is not present in the table. That's why
    #is.integer0 function is used
    HyRy <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRy"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRy"][[1]])
    HnRn <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRn"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRn"][[1]])
    HyRn <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRn"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRn"][[1]])
    HnRy <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRy"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRy"][[1]])

    contingencyTable <- matrix(c(HnRn,HnRy,HyRn,HyRy), nrow = 2)

    fisherTest <- fisher.test(contingencyTable) 
    newLine <- data.frame(t(c(humanReplicate = humanReplicateName, ratReplicate = ratReplicateName, pvalue = fisherTest$p,
                              alternative = fisherTest$alternative, Conf.int1 = fisherTest$conf.int[1], Conf.int2 =fisherTest$conf.int[2], 
                              oddratio = fisherTest$estimate[[1]])))


    result <-rbind(result,newLine)
  }
}

write.table(result, file = "newData5.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: The code provided in the [previous answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257433/r-passing-by-parameter-to-function-and-using-apply-instead-of-nested-loop-and-r/25331546#25331546) should be usable.